# Incensistent partition lag values when using high level consumer for reading Kafka logs

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, fluentd

All of our 30 topics are created with 10 partitions in our kafka.  We are monitoring the lag by partition for all the topics/group-ids.

We are using Fluentd plugin to read and route logs from kafka.  The plugin is implemented using a high level consumer. We have configured some consumers for individual topics and some for multiple topics for the plugin.  Overall, the data is flowing through with no problem except for 3 of the topics.

The problem is that for 3 out of the 30 topics being processed we see that the partition lag values are inconsistent ie. looking at lag values for a specific topic/group-id, the lag for some partitions are much higher than other partitions, sometimes by as much as 30k.  However, for the other 27 topics the lags numbers for all partitions stay uniform, all partitions of one topic/group-id stay within close range of each other (for ex. all between 12 and 18).

Almost every time we restart Fluentd agent (which restarts the high level consumers) we see that the lag starts to smooth out for those 3 topics and sometimes they stay consistent for a little while and then again lag numbers start to become zigzagy.  This is only happening for the 3 topics.  But when we check the distribution for those 3 topics, everything looks normal.

We are at a loss as the reason for this.  High level consumers do not code for managing the retrieval of the data from the partitions.  Its the kafka lib that handles that part. All that consumer code specifies is the number of threads.  We have tried 10, 5 and in all cases (especially 10 and 5 threads) the lag inconsistency keeps showing up for these 3 topics. The data volume is less than 30k per hour for each of these topics.

Any suggestion as to what could be the reason?  What can be done about it?

Really appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of the details provided I would start looking at the points below to begin with, I think so you would have already looked at them.

1. Compare the trend of messages being produced for the 3 topics versus rest of the topics. Also check the message sizes being published to these topics vs other topics.
2. Just move the problematic 3 topics to another fluentd instance to verify  lag behaviour.

Please do let me know incase you find anything more or solve the issue with some fine tunings

Comment: Thx for your response.  Yes, I had done those.  Nothing specific about those topics flow or the msg size.  We have other topics with lower and higher flow.  The message sizes are sort of small.   I have started another fluentd server with only those 3 topics and the same incosistent/zigzag lag values showed up.   I tested 6 other topics on the new servers and, just like on the original server,  all behaved as expected: consistent/smooth lag values for all partitions.
My guess is that there is something to do with these 3 topics in Kafka.  But can't guess what it can be.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the same 3 topics are being processed by antoher high level consumer using 1 thread, and the lags are all smooth.

Comment: Got it. Is there anything different at all as in number of partitions or replication that is different on these 3 topics. Is there any specific process that's done after fluentd consumes the message ( meaning any update to database or any other) for 3 topics vs others? How is the garbage collection on fluentd ? Does it look ok ?

Comment: All topics were implemented the same way, so no, there is nothing different about partitioning them.  Garbage collection is somethg we had not looked at yet.  However, still it's hard to think that some issue in fluentd only impacts these 3 topics and not the other 27 topics.  When we run these 3 with 1 thread by fluentd as well as by another HL consumer we don't see any zigzag issue with lag numbers for these 3 topics.  So, it seems that  only using more than 1 thread and only for these 3 topics is creating the zigzag lag values.

Comment: Understood your point. Would it be possible for you to share the picture of lag patterns?

Comment: there are 10 partitions and, in one case for one of the topics for ex, partition lags were: partition 0:15,1:15,2:16, 3:1355, 4:17, 5:14, 6:15, 7:13, 8: 1368, 9:14.    There is no pattern to the way lags are manifesting for one topic in diff tests, or between topics at any one point.  Its all over the place and very irradic.